# Inserted data not being shown in the database

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

My app will successfully build the SQLite database and insert data but when viewing it's empty apart from the column headings.

Permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

`QuoteDatabaseHandler` creates columns `ID` and `QUOTE`:

```
val QUOTEDATABASE = "QUOTE DATABASE"
val QUOTETABLE = "QUOTE_TABLE"
val COL_ID = "ID"
val COL_QUOTE = "QUOTE"

class QuoteDatabaseHandler (context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper (context, QUOTEDATABASE, null, 4) {

override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

    val createTable = ("CREATE TABLE $QUOTETABLE (COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,COL_QUOTE TEXT)")
    db?.execSQL(createTable)}
```

Insert function:

```
fun insertQuote (quote:String){

    val database =  this.writableDatabase
    val contentValues = ContentValues()

    contentValues.put(COL_ID, 1)
    contentValues.put(COL_QUOTE, quote)
    database.insert(QUOTETABLE, null, contentValues)
    database.close() }
```

`dbHelper` is called within `Oncreate`:

```
val dbHelper = QuoteDatabaseHandler(this)
```

Along with the insert method:

```
dbHelper.insertQuote("Example Quote 1")
```

Comment: don't edit your question to include the answer. Otherwise the answer no longer makes sense with regards to the question

Comment: Morning, I agree as you can see my edit was prior to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CREATE `TABLE` statement is wrong because it creates the table with columns named `COL_ID` and `COL_QUOTE` and not the correct names `ID` and `QUOTE`.

Use string interpolation for the column names:

```
val createTable = "CREATE TABLE $QUOTETABLE ($COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $COL_QUOTE TEXT)"
```

You will also have to uninstall the app from the device and rerun to recreate the table with the correct column names.